# FastAPI create auth for all endpoints

Tags: python, fastapi

I followed this documentation to setup up a single user:
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/http-basic-auth/

But I only get prompted for user/pass for that one end point, "/users/me".

How do I ensure that all endpoints are behind auth?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure FastAPI with a set of dependencies that needs to be resolved for any endpoint by giving the paramter directly when creating the FastAPI application (i.e. global dependencies):

```
security = HTTPBasic()

app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(security)])
```

If you want some endpoints to be authenticated and some to be unauthenticated, you can create separate instances of `APIRouter`, then assign required dependencies to the one that require authentication:

```
unauthenticated_router = APIRouter()
authenticated_router = APIRouter(dependencies=[Depends(security)])
```

.. and then either include other routers under each (using `.include_router`) or register endpoints as you'd do with the `app` object - but instead use your two routers.

Comment: How does it know what credentials should be used?

Comment: You handle that yourself in the method you've added your security dependency to. In the example given in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/http-basic-auth/ - this is the `HTTPBasicCredentials` object these days. This example only shows how to use the dependency across all nodes, in reality you'd make your own function that depends on this dependency and then verify the username/password there.

Comment: I have created a function `def authenticate(cred: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security))` which checks if username and passwords are correct, but this function gets triggered only when I trigger endpoint. My endpoint looks like this now: `def get_status(authenticated: bool = Depends(authenticate)):`. This requires me to add `authenticated: bool = Depends(authenticate)` parameter to every endpoint, is there a way so I wouldn't need to do that and authentication would be required for every endpoint?

Comment: Do what I've described in this answer? That's the way to do exactly that. If you have a new question, add relevant details _to a new question_ and why this doesn't solve what you're looking to do. It's hard to provide relevant details and code in comments, but in this case, replace `security` with `authenticate` above. Instead of returning `false` in your authentication point, raise an httpexception with 401/403 as its status code - that will terminated the request. If you want to still be able to check for authentication and not require it in certain endpoints, wrap the dependency

Comment: in another dependency: `def require_authentication(authenticated: bool = Depends(authenticate)): if not authenticated: raise HTTPException(status_code=401)` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise that I need to use `FastAPI(logger=logger, dependencies=[Depends(authenticate)])` instead of `FastAPI(logger=logger, dependencies=[Depends(security)])`

Comment: I tried `FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(get_current_active_user)]`, function in the docs tutorial to implement the auth to all path, but its not working. @vekeras

Comment: @curiouscheese Please create a new question with all the relevant details if you have a question; comments to an existing answer isn't the place to raise new issues.