# Enabling API Key Auth in FastAPI for all endpoints except / and a healthcheck endpoint?

Tags: python, authentication, fastapi

I want to implement basic api key auth for all endpoints of my FastAPI app except for `/` and `/health`.

I was going to do it using middleware, e.g.

```
@app.middleware("http")
async def validate_api_key(request, call_next):
    if is_production():
        api_key = request.headers.get("X-API-KEY")
        if api_key != settings.API_KEY:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=401, detail="Unauthorized"
            )
    response = await call_next(request)
    return response
```

However, this applies it to all endpoints including / and /health.

The next thing I read was that I could use SubApps, but that doesn't really make sense to me to have / and /health in one app, and then all my other endpoints in another app. Because it doesn't seem like you can mount them on the same prefix.

The other thing was to add it per endpoint using dependencies, e.g.

```
@app.get("/protected", dependencies=[Depends(api_key_auth)])
```

Taken from https://testdriven.io/tips/6840e037-4b8f-4354-a9af-6863fb1c69eb/
But that seems cumbersome to have to include it for every endpoint function that I write.

Is there a better way to just do simple api key auth for most endpoints?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/71150435/13877993

In `main.py`

```
import package1

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(package1.router)


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


@app.get("/health")
async def health():
    return {"message": "OK"}
```

in `auth.py`

```
from fastapi import HTTPException, Security
from fastapi.security import api_key

api_key_header = api_key.APIKeyHeader(name="X-API-KEY")


async def validate_api_key(key: str = Security(api_key_header)):
    if key != settings.API_KEY:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=401, detail="Unauthorized - API Key is wrong"
        )
return None
```

In `package1.py`

```
import auth
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends

router = APIRouter(dependencies=[Depends(auth.validate_api_key)])


@router.get("/my_endpoint")
async def my_endpoint():
    return {"message": "success"}
```